# Wordpress admin order Details Page how to get order id in php File?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Wordpress i want to send sms when admin cancel order from backed
i can not find how to get order id in back-end using php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the hook, You can directly send the mail.

In function.php file add this code,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'sent_custom_email', 21,1);
function sent_custom_email( $order_id ) {
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
}
```

Comment: how get $order_id in in admin order details area https://prnt.sc/yhaTiJRCCmLe

Comment: When you click on the canceled button from admin then you will auto get the $order_id with the using of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get order details from order id
 $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
if ( $order ) {
       // Get Order ID and Key
    $order->get_id();
    $order->get_order_key();
}
```

Comment: but i want to get it in admin order detail page 
https://prnt.sc/yhaTiJRCCmLe